# E_FAIL D3D11CreateDevice

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
ID3D11Device* md3dDevice;
ID3D11DeviceContext* md3dImmediateContext;
D3D_DRIVER_TYPE md3dDriverType = D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE;
HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
            0,                 
            md3dDriverType,
            0,                 
            D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, 
            0, 0,              
            D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
            &md3dDevice,
            &featureLevel,
            &md3dImmediateContext);ID3D11Device* md3dDevice;
```

I am getting an e_fail from this function when I include the D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag (works fine without flag). I assumed this had something to do with my debug runtime so I reinstalled the dx sdk as per the instructions in this thread: [What can cause D3D11CreateDevice() to fail with E_FAIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586956/what-can-cause-d3d11createdevice-to-fail-with-e-fail) It did not solve the problem though.

I am also still seeing zero debug levels in dxdiag:

```
--------------------
DirectX Debug Levels
--------------------
Direct3D:    0/4 (retail)
DirectDraw:  0/4 (retail)
DirectInput: 0/5 (retail)
DirectMusic: 0/5 (retail)
DirectPlay:  0/9 (retail)
DirectSound: 0/5 (retail)
DirectShow:  0/6 (retail)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The thread you linked by ["What can cause D3D11CreateDevice() to fail with E_FAIL?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586956/what-can-cause-d3d11createdevice-to-fail-with-e-fail?answertab=votes#tab-top) does contain the answer to your question I think.

I quote Chuck Walbourn:

> The latest version of the SDK Debug Layer is not in the legacy DirectX
>   SDK (June 2010) release. You need to install the standalone Windows
>   8.0 SDK, Visual Studio 2012, or you can just install the VS 2012 Remote Debugging Tools package.
>
> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update.aspx

For me installing the VS 2012 Remote Debugging Tools package solved the problem!