# VS Express 2010 KernelBase.dll _com_error DirectX11SDK

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directx

yesterday i tried to reinstall VS2010 Express after an reset of my system.
I installed VS2010 Express the Windows SDK 7.1 and the x64 Compilers as well as the DirectX SDK(June 2010).

At first i got an Error that he couldn't find Winmm.lib. I fixed this by adding the windows sdk directory to the Library Directorys.

Now Tutorial00 creates a window but whenever i start Tutorial01 the window appears and the closes and i get this error message:

`"First-chance exception at 0x000007fefd239e5d (KernelBase.dll) in Tutorial01.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x001feca0.."`

I think it's a problem with the DirectX SDK, because Tutorial00 doesn't use any DirectX features.

Any Suggestions how to solve the problem?

Comment: You probably installed the VS2010 Express first and then the DirectX? Did it work before you resetted your system?

Comment: hm.. actually i am not sure wheather i installed it before or after DirectX. Yes it worked before. So i Deinstall VS2010 and reinstall it?

Comment: For me and a few friends it always appeared installing VS before directX SDK caused this kind of trouble/errors. Before reinstalling make sure to deinstall the redistributable packages.

Comment: Might want to take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586956/what-can-cause-d3d11createdevice-to-fail-with-e-fail

Comment: Ok i deinstalled VS2010 all redistributable packages, the DirectX SDK and the windows sdk, cleared the registry and reinstalled it. I still got the same message. But your link seems to help when i compile in Release mode everything works fine. So i will try to fix this.